# Git keeps switching remote from ssh to https, finding root cause?

Tags: git

Every morning, I have a few repos configured with SSH remote URLs, yet it seems in the morning that they have switched to HTTPS URLs. I have to run `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com/xxx/xxx.git` to change it back.

Is there any way to figure out what's causing this? To my knowledge, no tool I use interacts with this git repo and I haven't been able to actually determine an action or time when it gets reset, it just happens to be switched when I get to work in the morning.

Is this something git does by default, if so why? And if not, how do I track down what's changing it?

My .git/config for the repo in question:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com/xxx/xxx.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "evolution-build"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/evolution-build
```

Comment: Take a look inside .git/config. What is written in this file?

Comment: @mbuechmann Added my .git/config

Comment: are you using something like dropbox/gdrive where you store your repos? probably initially they where cloned over http  but you keep changing the conf to ssh

Comment: @nbari Nope, they're rooted in C:\Users\user.name\Workspace and I do have Box installed but nothing that would sync/overwrite files in that directory (or they shouldnt be)

Answer (score 0):

> it seems in the morning that they have switched to HTTPS URLs

Before applying the git remote set-url, double check the origin URL was indeed an HTTPS one.

Then, double-check `git config -l` (the all config) for any `url....insteadOf git@bitbucket.example.com` rule: those would make Git use https for any SSH URL.

```
git config -l | grep -i insteadOf
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an internal tool was interacting with the git repo after all. It modifies the origin in some way to https. My workaround has been to make a new remote called `originssh` using the ssh URL that it will not modify. Pushing then becomes `git push originssh` instead.

Comment: `git config -l | grep insteadOf ` did not return anything?

Comment: @VonC Not in the few times that I've run it, no

Comment: Try with `git config -l | grep -i insteadOf` in case of a case sensitive issue. But if not, I don't know what could modify an HTTPS URL.

Comment: @VonC Nope, still nothing. Thanks for trying though :)