# Git remote URL is not updating to https://

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a new repo to GitHub, Whenever I try to update git remote in my local repo it is not updating properly

`$ git remote -v` will list me

`newOrigin       git://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git (fetch) newOrigin       git://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git (push)`

If I try to update the `git://` to `http://`

`git remote set-url  https://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git`

still, I'm getting the remote url as `git://..,` instead of `http://`

I'm getting this error while push

`git push -u newOrigin main fatal: remote error: You can't push to git://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git Use https://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git`

What is wrong here

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562088/7976758

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your command for setting URL worked? It seems to be missing a parameter.

```
git remote set-url <remote-name> https://github.com/xxx/Vuetest.git
```

This does seem to work well.

Also, `newOrigin` should not be `git://`, it should have been `git@github.com:xxx/Vuetest.git` if you used SSH to fetch it. Perhaps you made a mistake while changing URLs?

Comment: I have updated the image of my issue, after set url

Comment: Could you please also add your git version? I do not spot anything wrong with the command. The URL is incorrect but `set-url` should set anything as URL.